# matching regular expression in R

Tags: regex, r

I am trying to extract the matching pieces from a text paragraph using stringr- one of the text is

```
if returnValue is not null then 
1. if  instrument type is "Bond" then 
      Status is equals to 138 if the instrument is sensible coupon, 
      coupon type is not null and not equals to "ZERO COUPON" and previous value 
      is not equals to current value, and iinstrument creation date is not D 
- Status is equals to 137 if the instrument is sensible bbg, previous value 
      is not equals to current value, and iinstrument creation date is not D or D-1
- Status is equals  to the previous status if  the value is not manual 
        and previous status is 138, or 137

2. if attribute SEC_PAYT_DTE is not null then 
    if attribute SEC_PAYT_DTE (typed as date) is fresher than 
        returnValue (typed as date) then 
    set status to 136 that is "Functional Error"
3. if acrual date (DEBT_STRT_ACRL_DTE) is not null  and instrument 
        category is "Structured Product", and acrual date is different 
        frorm return value then 
  set status to 150 that is "Non blocking functional error".
```

what i want to extract is 'status 138','status 137', 'status 136','status 150'.

what I did is str_extract_all(x,'(S|s)tatus[a-z\s]{1,10}[0-9]{1,3}[^\.]'). but it doesn't work.

Comment: What are the rules here?  Please explicitly define what you want the regular expression to do

Comment: I want the regex to find the string 'S(s)status'+ 0-3 digit numbers that follows right after it. for example, 'the Status is equals to 138', regex should find 138. however, 1 in 'not D or D-1' should not be returned

Comment: So what should the line `and previous status is 138, or 137` return?

Comment: this should return 138 and 137. the 'status' string isn't important, but the number(s) right after it.

Comment: So do you just want all three-digit numbers then?

Comment: yes and no. first, the number is not necessarily 3 digit, can 1-3 digit. second,it has to be one RIGHT after 'status', otherwise, it is not really the status code. but I want the number, yes

Comment: @hwnd - `paste(text, vector)` usually.  I went to the chat room you invited me to. Did you check it?

Answer (score 0):

The regex matching in `str_extract_all` uses the POSIX standard, which does not continue looking on new lines, so you need to do this yourself.

```
matches <- sapply(strsplit(val, "\n")[[1]],
  str_extract_all, "[Ss]tatus is(?: equals to)? [0-9]+")
matches <- gsub(fixed = TRUE, "is ", "", gsub(fixed = TRUE, " equals to", "",
  Filter(length, matches)))
# [1] "Status 138" "Status 137" "status 138"
```